# MySQL: sub query returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to delete rows from responses table after the questions table has been updated but I get this error: sub query returns more than one row. Is there a way around to get it working?

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_responses AFTER UPDATE ON  questions
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NEW.active != OLD.active 
THEN DELETE FROM responses WHERE option_id = (
SELECT option_id
FROM options
WHERE question_id = OLD.question_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `=` to `= ANY` or `in`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_responses AFTER UPDATE ON  questions
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NEW.active != OLD.active 
THEN DELETE FROM responses WHERE option_id in (
SELECT option_id
FROM options
WHERE question_id = OLD.question_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `JOIN` instead:

```
DELETE r
FROM responses AS r
INNER JOIN options AS o ON r.option_id = o.option_id
WHERE o.question_id = OLD.question_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "in":

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_responses AFTER UPDATE ON  questions
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NEW.active != OLD.active 
THEN DELETE FROM responses WHERE option_id in (
SELECT option_id
FROM options
WHERE question_id = OLD.question_id);
```

or restrict your subquery so that it only returns one row.

Answer (score 0):

You can either limit the results of your subquery to 1 by limit or distinct, or if you ened to delete all founded results in the subquery you need to use `WHERE id IN (....)`